# Why is Brillouin zone a torus?

Tags: solid-state-physics, topological-insulators

I am told that Brillouin Zone is a torus, which plays an important role in defining chern number and other topological invariants. The argument is that Bloch wave function $\psi_k$ is periodical in reciprocal lattice vector: $$\psi_{k+G}=\psi_k$$.

However, chern number (and also other invariants) is defined using the periodic part of Bloch wave function $u_k$ ($\psi_k=e^{ikr}u_k$), which is not periodic in $k$: $$u_{k+G}=e^{-iGr}u_k$$. In many literature, to prove chern number is an integer, $u_{k+G}=e^{i\theta}u_k$ (notice that $\theta$ is $r$ independent!) is used, which is not consistent with the equation above.

So, in what sense Brillouin zone is a torus and why chern number is an integer with this understanding?

Comment: Bloch's theorem states that for a perfect crystal you can have a basis of wave functions so each is an energy eigenstate and can be written in the form of a plane wave times some function which has the same periodicity for whatever system you are talking about. If you restrict the range of ks then your wave functions will be unique. You get the torus by identifying the edges. If you have a 2d system with periodic BCs, you identify opposite edges corresponding to kx and ky to get a torus. Periodic BCs allow you to do this.