# Which property lead to the conclusion that BZ is a torus?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, crystals, topological-phase

In calculating the Chern number in 2D BZ, we assume that BZ is a torus. However, under periodic gauge, we have $\psi_k(r) = \psi_{k+G}(r)$, which means that $u_{k}(r) = u_{k+G}(r) e^{iG\cdot r}$. Since we express the Berry curvature in terms of $u_k(r)$, it seems that it's not obvious that we can identify $u_k$ and $u_{k+G}$ to form a torus. **So which property lead to the conclusion that BZ is a torus**? The comment in [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/295566/) is not satisfactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that for a periodic potential $V(r)$ such that $V(r+R) = V(r)$, the Hilbert space of wavefunctions is "smaller" than it would be for an arbitrary potential. Made precise, we know that the translation operator by a lattice vector $R_\mathbf{n}$, which I notate as
$\hat{T}_\mathbf{n}$, commutes with the Hamiltonian and therefore has simultaneous eigenstates. Label these eigenstates by $|E, \lambda_x, \lambda_y, \lambda_z \rangle$, such that

$H|E, \lambda_x, \lambda_y, \lambda_z \rangle = E |E, \lambda_x, \lambda_y, \lambda_z \rangle$

$\hat{T}_{(1,0,0)}|E, \lambda_x, \lambda_y, \lambda_z \rangle = \lambda_x |E, \lambda_x, \lambda_y, \lambda_z \rangle$

$\hat{T}_{(0,1,0)}|E, \lambda_x, \lambda_y, \lambda_z \rangle = \lambda_y |E, \lambda_x, \lambda_y, \lambda_z \rangle$

$\hat{T}_{(0,0,1)}|E, \lambda_x, \lambda_y, \lambda_z \rangle = \lambda_z |E, \lambda_x, \lambda_y, \lambda_z \rangle$

Further, because $\hat{T}$ is a representation of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ (i.e. all translations are reversible and can be applied arbitrarily many times), note that any translation can be written

$T_{n,m,l}|E, \lambda_x, \lambda_y, \lambda_z\rangle = \lambda_x^n\lambda_y^m\lambda_z^l|E, \lambda_x, \lambda_y, \lambda_z\rangle$

In order to preserve normalisation, we must have $|\lambda_i|=1$. We can therefore relabel the three $\lambda$ components with a vector $\mathbf{k}$ such that

$\hat{T}_\mathbf{n} |E, \mathbf{k}\rangle = e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot R_\mathbf{n}} |E, \mathbf{k} \rangle$

We now prove the key result: if $G$ is a reciprocal lattice vector (i.e. a vector such that for all lattice vectors $R_\mathbf{n}$, $R_\mathbf{n}\cdot G = 2\pi m, m\in \mathbb{Z}$), then

$$|E, \mathbf{k + G}\rangle = e^{i\theta}|E, \mathbf{k}\rangle$$

*Proof*. For any lattice vector $R_\mathbf{n}$,

$\hat{T}_\mathbf{n} |E, \mathbf{k + G}\rangle = e^{i(\mathbf{k+G})\cdot R_n} |E, \mathbf{k + G}\rangle = e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot R_n} |E, \mathbf{k + G}\rangle$
Since the eigenvalues are the same for all operators, we must conclude that $|E, \mathbf{k}\rangle = e^{i\theta} |E,\mathbf{k+G}\rangle$

If we define $\mathcal{H}$ as the Hilbert space of all electron wavefunctions,  in the periodic potential, Bloch's theorem tells us that there exists a basis of this Hilbert space where each ket has a well defined crystal momentum eigenvector $\mathbf{k}$. Each $\mathbf{k}$-subspace of $\mathcal{H}$ may then be regarded as a fiber over the 3-torus $\mathbb{R}^3/G$, corresponding to the first Brillouin zone.

The subtlety here is about smoothness of these kets with respect to the k parameter. For a long time, it was thought that the phase factors were not of any physical relevance - however, Berry's insight was that the kets should change *smoothly* with k, including across the BZ boundary, leading to nontrivial topological effects. The important part is that you cannot compare two phases at different points in the BZ directly - you must transport the state along a path.